# Form Submit Resource Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an mvc project with a form. The page loads up just fine, but when I click the submit button, I get this error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /commercialrecycling

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225

I'm running the form locally on my machine. How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an `[HttpGet]` attribute on the controller action? This would restrict a form post and return a 404 error

Comment: I added one for my Index method, but am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an action method called `commercialrecycling` of type `HttpPost`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourModel model)
{
  //Do for processing now
}
```

Assuming your form is a strongly typed to a model/Viewmodel called YourViewModel.

If you dont want to use the Model binding, you can simply use the parameters

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string username,string password)
{
  //Do for processing now
}
```

The parameter name should be same as the name of the HTML elements which you want to read data from.

Comment: You don't need to add the HttpPost attribute you just need to ensure the HttpGet is not applied. The method attribute restricts to the specified actions not allows the actions defined.

Comment: @MichaelGattuso : If you dont explicitly mention it as the [HttpPost] it will be considered as the GET verb. User clicked on submit in the form and he got the 404 error. That means the HttpPost action is missing.

Comment: CommercialRecycling is a different mvc project I'm working on which gave me this error when I merely tried to boot up the page. This new mvc project I'm working on is asking for something that appears different project. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jsmith: So What is your controller & action names for the current url

Comment: @jsmith: I guess it is Index Action in your home controller. The use Index action's HttpPost. I updated my answer

Comment: @Shyju - you are incorrect. Leaving off the HttpGet & HttpPost will mean that the action will handle both. From the docs on HttpPost "Represents an attribute that is used to restrict an action method so that the method handles only HTTP POST requests." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute.aspx) Note: the use of the word "only". These attributes restrict not permit.